# Running testng.xml file shows Invoked Methods error

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am getting Null pointer exception of Driver when i am running `selenium` with `testng.xml` file, if i directly run Login class it works fine. Also when i remove groups tag from .xml file it is running .xml but i want to use groups.
below is texng.xml:

```
    <groups>
        <run>

            <include name="Deal"  />
        </run>
    </groups>


    <classes>


    <class name="jproject.Login" />

    </classes>
</test>
```

My Login class is:

public class Login extends BClass{

```
    @Test (priority=1, groups = { "Nat", "Deal" }) // (description="This TC will perform valid login")

            public void LoginPage() throws InterruptedException 
            {   



                //Waits.loader(driver);
                String expectedTitle = "Clearview | Dashboard";
                String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
                Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);    

                Reporter.log("Application Logged in successfully | ");  


         }
```

}

In my Bclass i'm initializing driver and login under @BeforeSuite annotation.

Comment: It works fine when just Class name is there and i remove following code:  <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="Deal"  />
        </run>
    </groups>    But i need to use group to include or exclude it. Also this class has testcases with "Deal" group name but it's parent class does not has this group mentioned as that is my base class for for chrome drivers etc. please suggest

Comment: Most probably you are using some configuration methods @BeforeMethod etc. Make sure to add alwaysrun=true . When you are running using groups testng skipping those methods.

Comment: @ShaheryarKhawar - There's hardly any information in your post for anyone to find out what could have gone wrong. Request you to please edit your post, and add the code that is part of `jproject.Login` and also include the complete stacktrace of the error

Comment: Edited my question and code. Please suggest @KrishnanMahadevan

Comment: @ShaheryarKhawar - Please provide a full fledged example in your question for someone to take a jab at it along with the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix by replacing @BeforeSuite with @BeforeGroups in BClass
Thanks everyone!

Comment: In that case, you should accept your answer so that the question gets resolved.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan although its working fine but for just one class mentioned in .xml file. If i mention 2 classes then after running 1st class it shows Null pointer exception.          <classes>
        
        <class name="jproject.Login" />
        <class name="jproject.Dashboard" />

        </classes>